# In javascript, how to replace a letter with another in javascript object?

Tags: javascript

```html
var trim = function() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == 'a') {
            this[i] = 'b'
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know what's wrong with that code?

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be here? How are you calling `trim`?

Comment: It's not javascript, to start with *(`int`)*?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xoyfrz82/

Comment: Why you try to implement your function when you can use string replace function?

Comment: Other than the `int`, it should work if you call it in a way that sets `this` to your object, for example `x = ['a','b']; trim.call(x);`. (But it wouldn't work on a string.)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript strings are *immutable*. They are objects whose values can not be changed.

To wit:

```
var str = "hello";
str[2] = "x";
console.log(str); // outputs "hello"
```

To change a single character, you must split the string, and join it again.

```
"hello" -> "he" + "x" + "lo" -> "hexlo"
```

To replace a letter with another letter, a regex solution is better:

```
"aardvark".replace(/a/g, 'b'); // outputs "bbrdvbrk"
```